# Joining a view using an ID from external joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I am working with `SQL Server` and I faced a difficulty on joining some tables.

**Here is the scenario:**

I have the following tables:

- System
- Area
- Transfer

**Some more information about the tables:**

- Each area can have many Systems, but a System can be only in one Area.
- A System can have many Transfers, but a Transfer tuple can only be associated with one System.

I can join both `System` and `Area` together with the usual way, but for Transfer table, I would like to retrieve specific data and then join with the `System` and `Area`.

Here is my query

```
SELECT
    System.*,
    Transferring.SomeAttribute 
FROM
    System INNER JOIN
    Area ON Area.ID = System.AreaID INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            SomeAttribute,
            SystemID
        FROM
            Transfer
        WHERE
            Transfer.SystemID = {System ID ?}
        ORDER BY
            Transfer.Date DESC
    ) Transferring ON Transferring.SystemID = System.ID
WHERE
    Area.ID = @AreaID
```

The problem with the above is that I would like in the `Transferring` view to filter by the `SystemID` and return only the `TOP 1`.

If I remove the `WHERE` clause from the `view` and keep only the `SystemID = System.ID` on the joining will return wrong data as the `TOP 1` will happen first and then the `SystemID = System.ID`.

On the other hand, I would like to implement that in one `SELECT` statement and I prefer not to use two different queries.

**Just to make clear what I want from the above query:**
I would like to get information for all Systems in an Area, and the `SomeAttribute` for each System but the most recent one as the `Transfer` table will contain multiple transfers for each system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window function to find the latest transfer  per system, and then filter out those rows:

```
SELECT
    System.*,
    Transferring.SomeAttribute 
FROM
    System 
INNER JOIN
    Area ON Area.ID = System.AreaID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        SomeAttribute,
        SystemID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SystemID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        Transfer
    ) Transferring ON Transferring.SystemID = System.ID AND rn = 1
WHERE
    Area.ID = @AreaID
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the reason of the hard-coded `rn = 1` is that an example?

Comment: The inner query assigns a row number (named `rn`) to each row where the numbering is done in a descending order of the dates (see the inner `order by` clause), per different `SystemID` (see the `partition by` clause). As your requirement is to display the `SomeAttribute` of the latest transfer per system, this would be the first (`rn=1`) record according to the aforementioned ordering.

Comment: Would this not result in a table scan on Transfer or will the optimiser resolve this? Would it not be better to perform the `WHERE` within the nested SELECT? i.e. `SELECT
    Transferring.* 
FROM
     (
    SELECT 
 System.*,
        SomeAttribute,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SystemID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM System
 INNER JOIN  Transfer
 ON Transfer.SystemID = System.ID
 WHERE System.AreaID = @AreaID
    ) Transferring 
  WHERE Transferring.rn = 1`

Comment: @strickt01 I'd expect the optimizer to handle such a join properly, but I admit I haven't verified this with MS-SQL.